# Rellenar y enviar un formulario en una página web desde un programa en C o C++

Tags: c++, c, posix

Quiero enviar los datos de un formulario en HTML usando un programa en C o C++ al servidor y no sé el **formato o estructura** que deben tener los datos para ello. Básicamente quiero hacer lo mismo a lo que hace un **Submit** (o mas bien emularlo).

Sé los pasos que debo seguir:

1. Conectar con el servidor
2. Obtener el código HTML y analizarlo
3. Rellenar el formulario
4. **Enviar el formulario**
5. Cerrar conexión

Si este es el código HTML:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"> 
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

¿Cómo envío los datos al servidor usando C o C++?

Suponiendo que se use POSIX lo que quiero saber es cómo debo formatear la variable buffer:

```
send(*fd, **buffer**,buffer_size,0);
```

Comment: Te gustará [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response) pregunta.

Comment: El problema es justamente que esta basada en opiniones.. con que lo queres hacer? que probaste o intentaste de todo eso? Viene por ahi el tema de la pregunta, no por el largo.

Comment: Los pasos a seguir que comentas son muchos, yo mejor usaría curl para hacer un post directamente contra el action_page.php, mira este ejemplo: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html

Comment: Gracias lo miraré...

Comment: Si gbianchi... lo intenté... basicamente quiero saber que formato debe tener los datos para enviar con esta función                              send(*fd, buffer, bufer_size,0);                                                        (Es la función que usa POSIX para manejar Sockets)

Comment: Graicas **track3r**.... creo que lo que me has dicho que mire puede tener la solución.... voy a intentar enviarlo así   *buffer= "name=Mickey&lastname=Mouse" a ver si funciona... ya os contaré como me fue

Comment: ok, se me habia olvidado contar como me fue... ponerlo de esa manera me funcionó correctamente. Muchas gracias... Al final lo hice con wxWitgets... así
wxString request = wxT("GET /?name=Mikey \n");
socket->Write(request.mb_str(), request.Length());
Pueden cerrar el hilo. Asunto resuelto!! :-)